# Python script using import RE to put list of words into bracket

Tags: python, import

I would like to split the following string into a list. I have tried:

```
import re

mystr = """
MA1-ETLP-01
MA1-ETLP-02
MA1-ETLP-03
MA1-ETLP-04
MA1-ETLP-05
"""

wordList = re.sub("[^\w]"," ",mystr).split()
print wordList
```

I get the output:

```
['MA1', 'ETLP', '01', 'MA1', 'ETLP', '02', 'MA1', 'ETLP', '03', 'MA1', 'ETLP', '04', 'MA1', 'ETLP', '05']
```

I want it to look more like:

```
['MA1-ETLP-01', 'MA1-ETLP-02', 'MA1-ETLP-03', 'MA1-ETLP-04', 'MA1-ETLP-05']
```

How can I achieve the second output?

Comment: Why are you using `re` at all?

Comment: By _"put list of words into bracket"_, do you mean "make a list"?

Comment: where is mystr actually coming from?

Comment: `re.sub("[^\w]"," ",mystr)` replaces dashes (because they are not word characters) with spaces. `split()` without arguments splits on whitespace, hence your result.

Comment: I am trying to get it into that format so I can insert it into my fabfile, so I need it in that format for the env.hosts section

Comment: @aznjonn, are you reading the data from a file and calling .read?

Comment: @Jivan Your premise is disputed, see your meta-question: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/324032/well-asked-beginners-questions-keep-being-downvoted

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following will do the trick:

```
mystr.split()
```

Answer (score 7):

You don't need a regular expression for that. Just send the string to `split()`.

```
>>> mystr = """
...
...
... MA1-ETLP-01
... MA1-ETLP-02
... MA1-ETLP-03
... MA1-ETLP-04
... MA1-ETLP-05
...
... """
>>> mystr.split()
['MA1-ETLP-01', 'MA1-ETLP-02', 'MA1-ETLP-03', 'MA1-ETLP-04', 'MA1-ETLP-05']
```

Answer (score 1):

If you can have spaces in the lines you will want *splitlines* instead of split and to filter the empty lines:

```
mystr = """


MA1-ETLP-01
MA1-ETLP-02
MA1-ETLP-03
MA1-ETLP-04
MA1-ETLP-05

"""

print([line for line in mystr.splitlines() if line])
```

Based on the script name  `OpenFileAndFormat` it seems you are reading from a  file which if you are you need not split anything, you can read line by line into a list stripping newlines and filtering empty lines:

```
with open("your_file") as f:
    lines = [line for line in map(str.strip, f) if line]
```